# webcam does not work with my code

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to access the webcam with this code, when I run the code the frame opens but the webcam doesn't open to capture video. What is the wrong in this code?

[image]

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp> 
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> 
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp> 
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
char key;
int main()
{
    cvNamedWindow("Camera_Output", 1);    //Create window
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(CV_CAP_ANY);  //Capture using any camera connected to your system
    while(1){ //Create infinte loop for live streaming

        IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame(capture); //Create image frames from capture
        cvShowImage("Camera_Output", frame);   //Show image frames on created window
        key = cvWaitKey(10);     //Capture Keyboard stroke
        if (char(key) == 27){
            break;      //If you hit ESC key loop will break.
        }
    }
    key = cvWaitKey(10);
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture); //Release capture.
    cvDestroyWindow("Camera_Output"); //Destroy Window
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: calling cvQueryFrame(capture); twice fixed that problem for me before, try that

Comment: where should I put it?

Comment: "What is the wrong in this code?" It claims to be c++, yet the only c++ like thing is the ever so popular "using namespace std;" and for some obscure reason uses the long obsolete OpenCV C API, instead of the current c++ one.

Comment: put this line before the loop: cvQueryFrame(capture);